# OAuth2 in development and production

Tags: oauth-2.0, development-environment, production-environment

What is the best strategy of using OAuth2 authentication in development and production environment?

For example, I want to create an open source web based GitHub client. I have registered my client as GitHub application. According to OAuth2 spec I have to specify a redirect url while registering an application. What redirect_url should I use, localhost-based or real production url? If I use localhost-based (for development), my production site obviously stop working (and vice versa).

Is it safe to store client_id and client_secret in public code? If no, what is the best strategy to store it (i.e. in some config file that is not added to source version control system)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For rails, I used a gem called [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro).

You define environment-specific variables (config/application.yml):

```
CALENDAR_SCOPE: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar

production:
  CLIENT_ID: 393sdfgsdfg.apps.googleusercontent.com
  CLIENT_SECRET: sdfgdfsgsg
  OAUTH2_REDIRECT: http://mydomain/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback
  etc...

development:
  CLIENT_ID: 24asdfsadfas.apps.googleusercontent.com
  CLIENT_SECRET: asdfsadf
  OAUTH2_REDIRECT: http://localhost:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback
  etc....
```

You then use these in your code:

```
client = Google::APIClient.new({:auto_refresh_token => false})
client.authorization.scope = ENV['CALENDAR_SCOPE']
client.authorization.client_id = ENV['CLIENT_ID']
client.authorization.client_secret = ENV['CLIENT_SECRET']
client.authorization.redirect_uri = ENV['OAUTH2_REDIRECT']
etc...
```

You do have to remember to set the environment when starting the server. eg:

```
thin -e production start
```

or

```
thin -e development start
```

You probably would want to gitignore the application.yml file.

Comment: So you're using two separate application - one for production and one for development. Interesting idea. But how do you share your application.yml file between developers?

Comment: So the solution is to create OAuth client IDs as we need by environment and get all config from environment variables respectively?